# Blazor AOT dotnet.wasm is too big

Tags: blazor-webassembly, aot

We have a Blazor application, which we compile with AOT. The output dotnet.wasm is approximately 300 MB. And when we run the app, it uses 3GB of RAM in the Browser. And as a result, the app works slow, significantly slower compared to the Interpreter mode.

Is there a way to reduce the size of dotnet.wasm and the memory consumption?
Are there any tools to analyze it?

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version: 6.0.100-rc.1.21463.6
Commit: e627d556a1

Runtime Environment:
OS Name: Windows
OS Version: 10.0.19043
OS Platform: Windows
RID: win10-x64
Base Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-rc.1.21463.6\

Host (useful for support):
Version: 6.0.0-rc.1.21451.13
Commit: d7619cd
```

There is an issue for .NET 6 Preview 3,4,7, RC1

Maybe we attached too many 3rd party libraries. Is there a way to understand which libraries cause the issue?

Comment: WASM is still not very optimized. I have personally not moved to webassembly because it is still bloated and slow. Check this out (and the comment that comment refers to) : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35302#issuecomment-909430824